# Strange Routing error in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I am implementing an application in which i want to change the settings of the application.
While doing so I am getting an error

```
no routes matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"settings", format=>"nil"}
```

while clicking on the open `new settings` tab.

my `index.html` is as follows:-

```
<h1>Listing settings</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

  <% @settings.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= c.id %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.name %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.value %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.description %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this value?" } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Setting', {:action => 'new'} %>
```

My `settings controller` is as follows:-

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /setting
  # GET /setting.json
  def index
    @settings = Setting.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @settings }
    end
  end

  # GET /setting/1
  # GET /setting/1.json
  def show
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @setting }
    end
  end

  # GET /setting/new
  # GET /setting/new.json
  def new
    @setting = Setting.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @setting }
    end
  end

  # GET /setting/1/edit
  def edit
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /setting
  # POST /setting.json
  def create
    @setting = Setting.new(params[:setting])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @setting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @setting, notice: 'Setting was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @setting, status: :created, location: @setting }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /setting/1
  # PUT /setting/1.json
  def update
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @setting.update_attributes(params[:setting])
        format.html { redirect_to @setting, notice: 'Setting was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /setting/1
  # DELETE /setting/1.json
  def delete
   @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
   @setting.deleted = 1
   @setting.save

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to settings_url }
    format.json { render :json => { :success => true } }
    end
  end 
end
```

My `new.html` is as follows:-

```
<h1>New settings</h1>


<%= form_for @setting do |f| %>
<% if @setting.errors.any? %>  
  <div id="errorExplanation">  
    <h2><%= pluralize(@setting.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this setting from being saved:</h2>  
    <ul>  
    <% @setting.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
      <li><%= msg %></li>  
    <% end %>  
    </ul>  
  </div>  
 <% end %> 

Id: <%= f.text_field :id %><br>
Name: <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
Values: <%= f.text_field :value %><br>
Description: <%= f.text_field :description %><br>

<% end %> 

<%= link_to 'Back', settings_path %>
```

My routes.rb  is as follows:-

```
 Lms::Application.routes.draw do

     resources :books do
        member do
         post 'add'
         post 'remove'
        end

        collection do
         get  'add'
         get  'list' => "books#index"
         post 'get_books'
         get  'get_books'
        end
      end

      resources :books

      resources :book_transactions

      resources :book_issues

      resources :book_holds


      resources :categories


      resources :users


      resources :admins


      resources :library_locations


      resources :lov_values



      resources :loan_fines

      resources :lov_names

      resources :loans_fines do

       member do
         post 'add'
         post 'remove'
        end

        collection do
         get  'add'
         get  'list' 
         post 'get_loans_fines'
         get  'get_loans_fines'
        end
      end

       resources :settings do
         member do
         post 'add'
         post 'remove'
        end

        collection do
         get  'add'
         get  'list' 
         post 'get_settings'
         get  'get_settings'
        end
      end

      root :to => 'books#index'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

The strange part is that when i click on `new` action it is going/redirecting to the `show` action..I am a bit confused why this is happening..

Can some one help me with this..

Comment: what do you have in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @mihai please check the question ..I have edited it

Comment: your code looks ok, perhaps the problem is in the `new.html.erb` file...

Comment: do you get the same error if you were to use a resource route like so: link_to "New Setting", new_setting_path...ya, agree with mihai, you probably have a link_to in new.html that is not specified properly...probably because an instance is nil.  look for something like: link_to "setting", setting_path(@setting).  make sure @setting is not nil.  The exception should give you a line # and tell you exactly where the error is.  I also recommend BetterErrors gem: https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

Comment: @PeterP. I am getting undefined local variable or method 'new_setting_path'

Comment: @mihai I have updated the question can u please check

Comment: that's weird.  check your routes with: rake routes.  You should see an entry that says something like: "new_setting GET  /settings/new(.:format) settings#new"

Comment: @PeterP. Yeah i got it while running rake routes..Now what do I do

Comment: is new_setting_path working yet? do you have a line number on the exception?

Comment: @PeterP. nope i am not getting it yet...Also the line i am getting stuck is on  link_to "New Setting", new_setting_path ..line no 28

Comment: its difficult to debug at this point.  I would stick a debugger in the  index.html.erb view, and see what routes are available to you.  You can try: self.methods.grep(/_path/).sort

Comment: @PeterP. Where do I put the code You have mentioned.Can You please specify..I am not aware of this

Comment: I think you have an error in your view. check your `log/development.log`

Comment: @anonymousxxx there is an error in they view ie it is redirecting to another Url instead of the specified one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your routes you can run

> rake routes

to inspect if you have the routes defined correctly. Also I would suggest to use

```
<%= link_to "New Setting", new_setting_pah %>
```

For your routes definition you are not defining the routes for other methods than add or remove.
I advise you to read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) great tutorial on rails routes